# Generating RDP Profile Issue

Tags: c#, rdp, mstsc

I am working on a c# program, part of it is generating its own .rdp file that will automatically connect with all information provided when it is generated.

When I try to launch the rdp file from command line I get that it's not a valid connection profile. If I double click it in windows it opens up, connects and logs in.
So I know the password hashes that its generating are correct. I don't understand why its not valid via command line.

Here is what's being generated in the .rdp file

```
"full address:s:" + IP
"username:s:" + User
"domain:s:" + Domain
"password 51:b:" + Pass
"port:i:" + Port
"screen mode id:i:1"
"desktopwidth:i:800"
"desktopheight:i:600"
"session bpp:i:32"
"auto connect:i:1"
"autoreconnection enabled:i:1"
"compression:i:1"
"keyboardhook:i:2"
"audiomode:i:2"
"redirectdrives:i:1"
"redirectprinters:i:1"
"redirectcomports:i:0"
"redirectsmartcards:i:0"
"displayconnectionbar:i:1"
"alternate shell:s:"
"shell working directory:s:"
"disable wallpaper:i:1"
"disable full window drag:i:1"
"disable menu anims:i:1"
"disable themes:i:1"
"bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1";
```

Comment: How are you launching it from your code?

Comment: Also, you can remove all but the first 5 lines to troubleshoot if it's something weird in the extra options.

Comment: I figured it out, I was trying to launch it via mstsc.exe file.rdp /admin. If i just run the rep file directly it works fine. Maybe I miss understand what mstsc.exe wants as a connection profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, instead of trying to launch it via mstsc.exe file.rdp, I launch file.rdp instead and it works just fine.