# Give path as argument for mstsc.exe

Tags: c#, mstsc

I want to create a remote desktop connection with C#. I found this question [Run mstsc.exe with specified username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296819/run-mstsc-exe-with-specified-username-and-password).

At the moment I can create a new connection with username and password, but I want to change the path where the .rdp file will be saved.

Maybe you have an idea how I can change the save path.

Comment: bette that the default path, you can save the rdp file in that path ... try this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654992/generating-rdp-profile-issue

Comment: @KishoreSahas so I create a new file copy all important data inside and save it as .rdp? (= don't use mstsc.exe)

Comment: Yes i think that is better..

Comment: @KishoreSahas i tried it, but I got an error... What must be inside the .dpf file? Is the information (your link) enough? When I create a new .dpf File and open it with an editor its much longer as the file at the link.

Comment: @KishoreSahas Thanks for your help! I got it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Better that setting the default path, you can create the `rdp` file itself and save it in the default path.

the `rdp` file should contain the below content.

```
"full address:s:" + IP
"username:s:" + User
"domain:s:" + Domain
"password 51:b:" + Pass
"port:i:" + Port
"screen mode id:i:1"
"desktopwidth:i:800"
"desktopheight:i:600"
"session bpp:i:32"
"auto connect:i:1"
"autoreconnection enabled:i:1"
"compression:i:1"
"keyboardhook:i:2"
"audiomode:i:2"
"redirectdrives:i:1"
"redirectprinters:i:1"
"redirectcomports:i:0"
"redirectsmartcards:i:0"
"displayconnectionbar:i:1"
"alternate shell:s:"
"shell working directory:s:"
"disable wallpaper:i:1"
"disable full window drag:i:1"
"disable menu anims:i:1"
"disable themes:i:1"
"bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1";
```